# Get the nearest available value from the dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am having a dictionary
say

```
Dictionary<DateTime, double> MyData
```

Now I want to get the value from the dictionary.
But in case if the key does not exist then I need to take the nearest value.

Lets call a function

```
double GetMyData(Dictionary<DateTime, double> MyData, DateTime Date)  
    {  
      if(MyData.ContainsKey(Date)  
      {
          return MyData[Date];
      }  
      else  
      {  
          //return the nearest available value.  
          // if Date is '2018-01-01', then try to look for next date,  
          // It can be '2018-01-02' or even '2017-12-31'  
          // Here aim is to get the nearest available value.
      }  
    }
```

**EDIT :**
Sample Data :

```
MyData['2018-01-01'] = 420.0;  
MyData['2018-02-01'] = 220.0;  
MyData['2018-03-01'] = 320.0;  
MyData['2018-05-01'] = 210.0;  
MyData['2018-06-01'] = 220.0;   
MyData['2018-07-01'] = 230.0;  
MyData['2018-08-01'] = 240.0;
```

Here the key '2018-04-01' is not available,
So I need **any** of the nearest available value.
It can be the value of either '2018-03-01' or '2018-05-01'
Now I hope it is cleared.
And please No offence, English is not my native language.

Comment: Dictionary is not the data structure you require for this. You would need a 
 data structure that is ordered and is sequential. Something like a List. Or you could use a combination of dictionary  + sortedList

Comment: If I make it as a list then how would I get the value of that.  Problem is to find the nearest available Date (key) and then the value of that key. Anyway the key is Date which is already sorted. I just need to get the value of nearest available key.

Comment: Can you explain your actual task/problem? Also nearest in which way?

Comment: I'd probably use an _octree_.   Anyway your question is probably too broad

Comment: Dictionaries are used to look up the value associated with a key. They aren't structured in a way that allows for "close" lookups. Read up on "hash tables" to understand why. What you want is some sort of sorted list of `KeyValuePairs` sorted by the key, and then a lookup algorithm. You may find someone out on the internet with code that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution for this.

Step1 : sort (Descending) the keys less than the given Date and take the FirstOrDefault => `PreviousKey`
Step2 : sort (Descending) the keys greater than the given Date and take the FirstOrDefault => `NextKey`

Step3 : Now check the difference between them
Step4 : If (`Date`-`PreviousKey`)>(`NextKey`-`Date`) then take `NextKey` else `PreviousKey` => `FoundKey`
Step5 : Now, return MyData[FoundKey]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a **ordered** dictionary, and not only that, you'll need to have a custom comparer to **find the closest date to the key**

See the minimal sample code below

```
void Main()
{
    OrderedDictionaryByDateTime<double> data = new OrderedDictionaryByDateTime<double>();
    data.Add(DateTime.Now, 1.1);
    data.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), 1.2);
    data.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), 1.3);
    data.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), 1.4);
    data.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5), 1.5);

    var tomorrow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    var oneHourBefore = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    var theDayAfterTomorrow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
    var yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    var fourDaysInThePast = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4);

    data.GetValueClosestToTheDateTimeKey(tomorrow); // should be 1.1
    data.GetValueClosestToTheDateTimeKey(oneHourBefore); // should be 1.1
    data.GetValueClosestToTheDateTimeKey(yesterday); // should be 1.2
    data.GetValueClosestToTheDateTimeKey(theDayAfterTomorrow); // should be 1.3
    data.GetValueClosestToTheDateTimeKey(fourDaysInThePast); // should be 1.5
}

public class OrderedDictionaryByDateTime<TValue> : List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, TValue>>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<DateTime, int> _dictionary = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();

    public void Add(DateTime key, TValue value)
    {
        Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, TValue>(key, value));
        _dictionary.Add(key, Count - 1);
    }

    public TValue Get(DateTime key)
    {
        var idx = _dictionary[key];
        return this[idx].Value;
    }

    public TValue GetValueClosestToTheDateTimeKey(DateTime key)
    {
        var closestDate = _dictionary.Keys.OrderBy(t => Math.Abs((t - key).Ticks)).First();

        return Get(closestDate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use code below,

Code sort dictionary by key (DateTime) and find GreaterOrEqual date values. If there is a valid record returns first value, else return -1

```
    public double? getData(Dictionary<DateTime,double> source, DateTime date) 
    {
        if (source.Where(x => x.Key >= date).OrderBy(x => x.Key).Count() > 0)
            return source.Where(x => x.Key >= date).OrderBy(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault().Value;
        else
            return -1;
    }
```

If you want to get nearest value ( up or down ) you can use code below,

```
    public double? getData(Dictionary<DateTime,double> source, DateTime date) 
    {
        DateTime up = source.Where(x => x.Key >= date).OrderBy(x => x.Key).Count() > 0 ? source.Where(x => x.Key >= date).OrderBy(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault().Key : DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime down = source.Where(x => x.Key <= date).OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).Count() > 0 ? source.Where(x => x.Key <= date).OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault().Key : DateTime.MinValue;

        long up_difference = -1;
        long down_difference = -1;

        if (up != DateTime.MinValue)
            up_difference = up.Ticks - date.Ticks;

        if (down != DateTime.MinValue)
            down_difference = date.Ticks - down.Ticks;

        // There are no values upper or higher
        if (up_difference == -1 && down_difference == -1)
            return null;
        else if (up_difference != -1 && down_difference != -1)
        {
            if(up_difference < down_difference)
                return source.Where(x => x.Key == up).FirstOrDefault().Value;
            else
                return source.Where(x => x.Key == down).FirstOrDefault().Value;
        }
        else if(up_difference != -1)
        {
            return source.Where(x => x.Key == up).FirstOrDefault().Value;
        }
        else
        {
            return source.Where(x => x.Key == down).FirstOrDefault().Value;
        }

    }
```

Comment: That's terribly inefficient

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put the dictionary in a sorted dictionary and do a binary search.
    If the key doesnt exist, then the item on the left is the nearest one.
    This doesn't cater for boundary scenarios where ~index - 1 becomes -1 etc...

```
public static double GetMyData(Dictionary<DateTime, double> MyData, DateTime Date)
{
        var sorted = new SortedDictionary<DateTime, double>(MyData);

        var keys = new List<DateTime>(sorted.Keys);
        var index = keys.BinarySearch(Date);

        if (index >= 0) return sorted[keys[index]];

        else
            return sorted[keys[~index - 1]];
    }
```

Comment: In this search, Date is never present. So not helpful in searching this but we need the nearest either greater than or less than the given date.

Comment: This seems the way to go. What what the problem with this solution @Karthik? If possible you should change the Input dictionary to SortedDictionary so you dont need to create one all the time in here.

Comment: You can do number of days from previous and after and then return the value from lesser of the days..compare abs(Date - keys[~index - 1]) and abs(Date-keys[~index + 1] etc..

Answer (score 0):

If u need nearest value , u need to loop thru dictionary and take lowest time span and remember the lowest and return that DateTime.

```
TimeSpan timeSpan=DateTime.MinValue-DateTime.MaxValue;
double returnDate;
foreach(var key in MyData.Keys)
{
  if(key<Date)
  {
    var dif = Date-key;
    if(dif<timeSpan)
    {
     timeSpan=dif;
     returnDate=MyData[key];
    }
  }
  else
  {
    var dif = key-Date;
    if(dif<timeSpan)
    {
     timeSpan=dif;
     returnDate=MyData[key];
    }
  }
 }
  return returnDate;
```

Comment: There is nothing to do with  the timespan. My data is already sorted. I just want to get the available key's value from the dictionary. if a key is not available then try to take next one. And the next one can be any date. Its not just a timespan.  If a key '2018-02-01' is not available then I have to take the next nearest one.

Comment: I understand , but this does the trick i think!? Because this gonna return the nearest date to your Date parameter! It's gonna go thru all keys and look for the closest one, btw i din't test this.